# Big Data ingestion - Flafka use cases

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume-ng

I have seen that the Big Data community is very hot in using Flafka in many ways for data ingestion but I haven't really gotten why yet.

A simple example I have developed to better understand this is to ingest Twitter data and move them to multiple sinks(HDFS, Storm, HBase).

I have done the implementation for the **ingestion** part in the following two ways:
(1) Plain Kafka Java Producer with multiple consumers (2) Flume agent #1 (Twitter source+Kafka sink) | (potential) Flume agent #2(Kafka source+multiple sinks). I haven't really seen any difference in the complexity of developing any of these solutions(not a production system I can't comment on performance) - only what I found online is that a good use case for Flafka would be for data from multiple sources that need aggregating in one place before getting consumed in different places.

Can someone explain why would I use Flume+Kafka over plain Kafka or plain Flume?

Comment: After trying it yourself what are your own conclusions ?  Did you do some research yourself ? if so what did you get from them and what is you feel is still missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People usually combine Flume and Kafka, because **Flume** has a great (and battle-tested) set of **connectors** (HDFS, Twitter, HBase, etc.) and **Kafka** brings **resilience**. Also, Kafka helps distributing Flume events between nodes.

EDIT:

> Kafka replicates the log for each topic's partitions across a
>   configurable number of servers (you can set this replication factor on
>   a topic-by-topic basis). This allows automatic failover to these
>   replicas when a server in the cluster fails so messages remain
>   available in the presence of failures. -- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#replication

Thus, as soon as Flume gets the message to Kafka, you have a guarantee that your data won't be lost. NB: you can integrate Kafka with Flume at every stage of your ingestion (ie. Kafka can be used as a source, channel and sink, too).

Comment: Is it possible to explain a bit more on your last sentence? Do you just mean that Kafka will replicate the data(for fault tolerance) received from a Flume agent?